# Java: how to initialize child when super constructor requires parameter

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, subclass, inheritance

I have

```
class A {

    int var;
    public A(int x) {
        var = x;
    }
}


class B extends A {
     int var2;

     public B(int x, int y) {
         super(...);
         var2 = y;
         x = f(y);
     }
 }
```

For the subclass B, I need to calculate the value x that is used in the constructor of A.  If I were free to move `super` below my `x=f(y)` then I could pass in the result to the constructor of A (super).  But super has to be the first line in the constructor of B.

Is there any way to initialize A with the proper value the first time?  What if A.var were final and i couldn't go back and change it after construction?

Sure, I could put `super(f(y))`, but I could imagine cases where this would become difficult.

Comment: Why are you taking `int x` as a parameter for the `B()` constructor at all here?

Comment: If @hvgotcodes solved your answer, then please accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `var` is private and you **need** to set the value with the constructor (which seems to be the point of the question, otherwise there are many easy solutions), I would just do it with a static factory-like method.

```
class B extends A {
     int var2;

     public static B createB(int x, int y) {
         x = f(y);
         return new B(x, y);
     }

     public B(x, y) {
         super(x);
         this.var2 = y;
     }
 }
```

something like that.  You have no choice, as explicit constructor invocation must happen on the first line of the wrapping constructor.

Comment: he says he knows he can do that.  the point of the question is 'what If I need to...'

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this :

```
class B extends A {
    int var2;

    public B(int x, int y) {
        super(calculateX(y));
        var2 = y;
    }

    private static int calculateX(int y) {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Calling a static method is the only thing you can do before calling the superclass constructor.

Comment: Further, you can get hold of the value by calling a "this()" constructor call: `public B(int y) { this(y, calc(y)); } private B(int y, int z) { super(z); ... use y & z ... }`

Comment: interesting.  Although not indicated in my question, my calculateX(y) is actually a generic method, so the compiler complains that I can't make the method static since E (the template parameter) is non-static.

Comment: @darKoram You can make the static method generic.

Comment: Well you can, but the generic parameters would only apply to that particular method. Darkoram's generic parameter is, I think, a class-level one, so it only makes sense in the context of a particular instance of the class - so the static method cannot use that generic placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to hvgotcodes, since it looks like you also want to set A's variable...

```
class B extends A {
 int var2;

 public B(int x, int y) {
     super(x);
     var2 = y;
     x = f(y);
     super.var = ...;
 }
}
```

Comment: @hvgotcodes: Correct, and in the example provided, var defaults to public.

Comment: I think the intention of the question is 'what if I need to call the super constructor'.

Comment: Clearly this works, but I was hoping to make A.var final, so it can only be set once.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to add a protected constructor without parameters to A that relies on lazy initialization:

```
class A {
    int var;

    public A(int x) {
        var = x;
    }

    /**
    * Just use this constructor if you initialize var
    */
    protected A(int x) {
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int var2;

    public B(int x, int y) {
        super();
        var2 = y;
        var = f(y);
    }
}
```

But that's hard to document, not very obvious to team members and shouldn't be used for an api.

Comment: I like this approach best so far, but I want to have this class in the API

Comment: when you say it's hard to document do you mean you'd have to copy it to any siblings?   Is that something that annotations can handle elegantly?

Comment: That could work. The point is you have to initialize class members from the super class, that's usually not very obvious to api users. Therefore it needs to well documented (especially which methods are used to transform the parameters in the public contructor). Also depends on how likely api users would extends this class, if it's just fot another class in the api, an element comment like "Do not use" would also work.

Comment: I just tried this construct and the compiler won't let me make a constructor for A with var as final without setting its value in the constructor.

Comment: Right, that's also a drawback. I had this problem myself recently. It's an ugly solution, as said. Only other thing I could come up with would be introducing an interface (or abstract class) that both classes implement and making B an own class that doesn't extend A, but this most likely would lead to duplicate code (except you can move some of the methods to the abstract class).